# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' AsyncPipe Ionic Angularfire2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

#### feed.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, MenuController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemDetailsPage } from '../item-details/item-details';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { UserService } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireObject } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Items } from '../../models/item_interface';
import { ItemService } from '../../providers/item-service/Item-service';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-feed',
    templateUrl: 'feed.html',
})
export class FeedPage {

    item = 'Found';

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                public menu: MenuController,
                private db: AngularFireDatabase,
                private iServ: ItemService)
    {
        this.menu.swipeEnable(true);
    }

    itemName(type:any) {
        this.items = this.db.list(`items/${type}`);
        return this.items;
    }

    getDetails(itemN: any) {
        this.navCtrl.push(ItemDetailsPage,{item: itemN});
    }

    getColor(item) {
        return (item === "Found")
                   ? "primaryGreen"
                   : "primaryRed";
    }
}
```

#### feed.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title text-center>Feed</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <h2 text-center>{{ item }}</h2>

    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="item" color="primaryBlack">
      <ion-segment-button value="Found">
        <ion-icon name="hand"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="Lost">
        <ion-icon name="help"></ion-icon>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>

    <ion-list style="margin:0" inset>
      <button ion-item detail-none *ngFor="let i of (itemName(item) | async)" (click)="getDetails(i)">
        <ion-card padding [color]="getColor(item)">
          Item: {{ i?.itemN }} <br>
          <!-- Location: {{ i.itemLocation }} <br>
          Description: {{ i.itemDescription }} <br> -->
          <p style="color:#f6f6f6;font-size: 9px; margin-top: 5px">Posted by: </p>
        </ion-card>
      </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

#### Item-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Items } from '../../models/item_interface';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

    items: AngularFireList<Items>;
    userId: string;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private aAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
        this.aAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            if (user)
                this.userId = user.uid;
        })
    }

    getItems(query: string):AngularFireList<Items>{
        if(!this.userId)
            return;
        this.items= this.db.list(`items/${query}`);
        return this.items;
    }

    createItem(item: Items,query:string){
        this.items = this.getItems(query);
        item.userId = this.userId;
        this.items.push(item);
    }
}
```

#### Items:

```
export interface Items {
    itemN:string;
    itemLocation: string;
    itemDescription: string;
    userId: string;
}
```

I went through a lot of the solutions, but couldn't figure this out. Some suggested using the list as an observable list. The observable list now has been changed to `AngularFireList`. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hi, so looking at your code i think you should consider refactoring it. Basically think about the ngFor as of something that will get called often and look at how many things javascript will have to do. Can you add to your question higher pevel context of what you are trying to achieve? Like rendering list from firebase and any details of requirements that you have.

Comment: I finally found my error. The error was my older version of rxjs@5. When I updated to rxjs@6 and added it to be observable changing it to snapshotChanges() it worked. 
I was trying to display data on the basis of two keys which would be determined by ion-segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your function `itemName` returns not an observable but an object an `AngularFireList` object and to make an observable out of it you need to call function `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()`, but for now just use the first one it will be much simpler for you. Change your function like:

```
itemName(type:any){
  this.items = this.db.list(`items/${type}`).valueChanges();
  return this.items;
}
```

Comment: I finally found my error. The error was my older version of rxjs@5. When I updated to rxjs@6 and added it to be observable changing it to snapshotChanges() it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The error was with my older version of rxjs@5. When I updated to rxjs@6 and added it to be observable changing it to snapshotChanges() it worked.

You can check the version of rxjs by using npm list --depth=0

```
itemName(type:any){
    this.db.list(`items/${type}`).snapshotChanges().subscribe(
      list => {
        this.itemArray = list.map(i => {
          return {
            $key: i.key,
            ...i.payload.val()
          }
        });
      }
    );
    return this.itemArray;
  }
```